# Could not find twitter-1.6.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I'm trying to install the bundles but it can't install twitter-1.6.2 in specific.

```
mauricio@mauricio-ubuntu:$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Could not find twitter-1.6.2 in any of the sources
```

Could someone help?

Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter'
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
twitter (1.6.2) 
  faraday (~> 0.7.4) 
  faraday_middleware (~> 0.7.0)
  hashie (~> 1.1.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.0.0)
  multi_xml (~> 0.2.0)
  simple_oauth (~> 0.1.5)
```

I'm using ruby 1.8.7-p334 (I know, it's old).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ gem list ^twitter$ --remote --all

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

twitter (4.8.1, 4.8.0, 4.7.0, 4.6.2, 4.6.1, 4.6.0, 4.5.0, 4.4.4, 4.4.3, 4.4.2, 4.4.1, 4.4.0, 4.3.0, 4.2.0, 4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.0)
```

You aren't even close.

Ahh,

1) Go here:

https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter/

2) Scroll to the bottom, and click on *Show all versions*.

3) Click on 1.6.2.

4) Now even though the next page doesn't show version 1.6.2 in the list of versions, just click on the Download link(above the list of versions)

5) Install the gem:

1. If you are using rvm, switch to whatever gemset you created for your current project.
2. Install the twitter gem:

   $ gem install --local /path/to/twitter.gem

The `bundle install` command is not supposed to go looking for gems to download if the version specified in your Gemfile is already installed.  To be safe, I would change the twitter line in your Gemfile to this:

```
gem 'twitter', '1.6.2'
```

Comment: Gemfile: gem 'twitter'

Gemfile.lock: twitter (1.6.2)
      faraday (~> 0.7.4)
      faraday_middleware (~> 0.7.0)
      hashie (~> 1.1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0.0)
      multi_xml (~> 0.2.0)
      simple_oauth (~> 0.1.5)

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano, I can't read that.  Add it to your original post.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano, I did some searching, and I posted what I think is the state of affairs with rubygems.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano, you can do it. See additions.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano, if you want to be of service to future old gem installers, add the following to your post title: `installing yanked gems`